# Is it possible to Brush a DrawingVisual?

Tags: wpf, brush

I am working with DrawingVisual in WPF and want to make some Effect.

Is it possible to brush a DrawingVisual with any brushes? That means:

Suppose I have a DrawingVisual:

```
DrawingVisual myVisual = new DrawingVisual();

myVisual.RenderOpen().....
.....
....
....
```

No matter how I draw, I want to make the whole visual to be in a color brush at the end.

something like:   drawingcontext.drawvisual(myVisual, Brushes.Red) ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A DrawingVisual is not itself a drawing object that can be filled with a Brush or outlined with a Pen. Instead it is a container for [Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawing.aspx) objects (and for other visuals, since it is also a [ContainerVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.aspx)).

If you want to "fill" a DrawingVisual with a "background" brush, you would have to draw an appropriate Drawing, e.g. a large enough filled rectangle.